# How do you select multiple aggregates and a non aggregate in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this TSQL statement which seems simple enough

```
select qGroup, AVG(score), COUNT(score)
  from [Scores]
  where [year] = 2014 and charIndex('s', qGroup, 0) <> 1
  group by qGroup
```

However, I just cannot figure out how to express this in LINQ (dot notation)

Here is my failed stab at it

```
List<qGroupModel> query = context.Scores.Where(p => (p.schoolID == schoolID) && (p.Year == year) && !(p.qGroup.StartsWith("S"))).Select(p => new { p.Average(p2 => p2.Score), p.qGroup }).GroupBy(p => p.qGroup).ToList<qGroupModel>();
```

The error I get from the above is as follows

> 'Models.Score' does not contain a definition for 'Average' and no
>   extension method 'Average' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Models.Score' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

My LINQ acumen is not so great.. but still.. this seems harder than it should.

Please help

Comment: This seems to compile... `var thisYearScores = scoreRepo.GetAll().Where(p => (p.schoolID == schoolID) && (p.Year == year) && !(p.qGroup.StartsWith("S"))).GroupBy(p => p.qGroup).Select(p => new { avgScore = p.Average(p2 => p2.Score), qGroup =  p.Select(p3 => p3.qGroup)});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
List<qGroupModel> query = 
                    context.Scores
                           .Where(p => (p.schoolID == schoolID) && (p.Year == year) && !(p.qGroup.StartsWith("S")))
                           .GroupBy(p => p.qGroup)
                           .Select(p => new qGroupModel { p.Average(p2 => p2.Score), p.qGroup })
                           .ToList();
```